# "Гуральня" чи "Ґуральня"?

Tags: вибір-слова, іменники

На позначення спиртово-горілчаних заводів є питомо українське слово, от тільки як його правильно писати?

В СУМ-11 немає слова "[гуральня](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghuraljnja)", але є слово "[ґуральня](http://sum.in.ua/s/guraljnja)", але якщо подивитися на сам [словник](http://sum.in.ua/p/2/195/2) — стає зрозуміло, що це просто помилка, а слово - таки "гуральня".

Тоді дивлюся "СУМ-20":

> **ҐУРА́ЛЬНЯ**, і, ж., заст. Спирто-горілчаний завод. Там в березі є човни управителя ґуральні, на котрих рибалки ловлять коропи (І. Нечуй-Левицький); Того вечора зупинилась панська ґуральня: насос, що подавав воду з ставка, зіпсувався (В. Кучер); У винниківській улоговині поблизу ґуральні пана Залеського притулилася до жовтого горба така мізерна халабудка (Р. Іваничук).

Статті "гуральня" в СУМ-20 немає.

У [Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8F):

> Гура́льня, ні, ж. = Ґуральня. Ном. № 11659.
>
> [Ґура́льня](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D2%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8F), ні, ж. Водочный заводь.

Отже, маємо:

- СУМ-11: гуральня
- СУМ-20: ґуральня
- Грінченко: гуральня=ґуральня

Кому з них вірити, як це перевірити, чи обидва слова літературні, чи лише одне з них? Невже СУМ-20 брав електронну версію СУМ-11, копіював її й не перевіряв?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Етимологічний словник української мови засвідчує наявність звуку [*ґ*] в сьому слові [image]

Answer (score 3):

Якшчо поглянути знов на словник, то можна помітити — там лиш буква *г*, цєбто *ґ* взагалі нема, як належить [покрокового напряму](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%90#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%B4) Совіцької узурпацької влади за змосковченя украӥнської. Цє помітно і за такими словами як [*ґазда*](http://sum.in.ua/s/gazda), [*аґрус*](http://sum.in.ua/s/agrus), [*ґирлиґа*](http://sum.in.ua/s/gyrlyga) тошчо, котрі відоміші зі затверџеним вживом букви *ґ*, але тоді записані, як належно за лінією партіӥ, буквою *г*. Тому цє не «просто помилка», а належне, хоч і не зовсїм послїдовне — порівняьте: [*жюрі*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhjuri) не замінили, а просто вказали на застарілість *(можливо через те, шчо цє було шче з клясичного)* — виправленє авторами електроного словника.

Коли вже розлядати на правильність слова з, як належно, врахуванєм букви *ґ*. То на першиь погляд наче нема ріжницӥ — першопнєм є знаьме *гор* від *горіти* (тут від польського [*gor**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D2%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8F), де *g = ґ*), отже довід за *г*. Однак з цӧго також випливає: *у* стає *о*, отже *горальна* — в описах є навіть згадане *горілчаниь*. Але питанє тут лиш про *г*, отже арґумент обернениь: з типовим декотрозахідним *уканєм* при ненаголошеного *о* (тут наголос на *а*) мусить збереги і *ґеканя*.

До цӧго ж арґументу: провідні словники, хоч і деякі з деякими сумнівніми якостями, наводять саме *ґ*, шче ж бо Грінченко *наводить* на слово з *ґ*, а не навпаки.

Висновок: **ґуральня**.

Comment: що значить "отже довід за г"?

Comment: ви кажете, що це слово могло б бути навіть "горальня"? найближче тоді до горілки?

Comment: @P.Vowk Повторьуьу: «першопньем ье знаьме _гор*_ від _горьіти_, [...] отже довід за _г_» — _ґорьіти_ і подальш, так звана звичаьева украьинська не маье, а _горьіти_, _горьачиь_ і подальш маье. Так, _горьілка_ теж походить від цього пньа.